# ruamel.yaml weird behavior when dumping floats

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

When I read my YAML, it is fine if I print with ordered dict, but when I dump it, my floats get hosed somehow.

Here is a minimal working example

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()   

s = 'f: [2330.0e6, 2338.0e6]'
d = yaml.load(s)

yaml.dump(dict, sys.stdout)
print(d)
```

This outputs

```
f: [2330.0e6, 2340.0e6]
ordereddict([('f', [2330000000.0, 2338000000.0])])
```

The ordered dict is correct, but the YAML dump changed the number to 2340...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is probably not the whole program.

You are loading into variable `d`, but you are dumping `dict` and the latter normally gives a `RepresenterError` as the built-in dict class itself cannot be dumped (of course an instance thereof **can** be dumped)

If I run on python 3.8:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()   

s = 'f: [2330.0e6, 2338.0e6]'
d = yaml.load(s)

yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
print(d)
```

I get

```
f: [2330.0e6, 2338.0e6]
ordereddict([('f', [2330000000.0, 2338000000.0])])
```

as expected.

Comment: I'm on 2.7 but maybe I should try upgrading ruamel.yaml?

Comment: Also, this wasn't a complete program, it was a minimal working example. No reason to include 500 lines of code if the issue can be demonstrated in 7 lines :)

Comment: Python 2.7 gives the same `ReprsenterError` as does Python 3.8, so that is not the output and the rest of your program somehow used `dict` as a variable., Upgrading ruamel.yaml could maybe help,  but I don't recall fixing a bug like the one you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Anthon inspired me to upgrade my ruamel.yaml (from 0.15). I'm on Python 2.7 (I know it's not supported anymore, long story...)

Anyways, pip install --upgrad ruamel.yaml fixed the issue :)